# How to skip last operation in recursive function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

There is a recursive function like this:

How do I exclude the last iteration and dont get last node in tree?

```
export function getFullName(treeNode: TreeNode, fullname = ''): string {
    if (treeNode.parent) {
        if (fullname) fullname = `${treeNode.name}/${fullname}`;
        else fullname = treeNode.name;

        fullname = getFullName(treeNode.parent, fullname);
    }

    return fullname;
}
```

Comment: I can push `fullname` to array then return array.splice(-1).join("/")

Comment: Please provide some example input and expected output

Comment: don't use recursion, make use of e.g. `while` instead ... `while (treeNode = treeNode.parent) { ... }`

Comment: What is the `treeNode` structure?

Comment: treeNode is `{id: number, name: string, parent: treeNode}`

Comment: I agree with @PeterSeliger, actually the reason you use tree Structure most of time because you want to make use of the structure and make searching easily.

Comment: in case one has to stick to recursion one needs an additional `if` clause before stepping into the next recursion level ... `if (treeNode.parent) { fullname = getFullName(treeNode.parent, fullname); }`

Comment: Could you share an example with while?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the reason you use tree Structure most of time because you want to make use of the structure and make searching easily.

You can use while loop to check if parent node exist instead of recursive.

```js
class TreeNode {
  constructor(id, name, treeNode) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.parent = treeNode === undefined ? null : treeNode;
  }
}

const node1 = new TreeNode(1, "node1");
const node2 = new TreeNode(2, "node2", node1);
const node3 = new TreeNode(2, "node3", node2);

function getFullName(treeNode) {
  let node = treeNode;
  let fullName = "";
  while (node) {
    fullName = `${node.name}/${fullName}`;
    node = node.parent;
  }

  return fullName;
}

const output = getFullName(node3);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Where is concatination string?

Comment: @user13314476,  `${node.name}/${fullName}`

Comment: How does it work you dont have fullname+=fullname`

Comment: @user13314476, ```fullName = `${node.name}/${fullName}`;``` is equal to  `fullName = node.name + "/" + fullName;`